# FB.ui method:'send' messages always end up in users primary inbox?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

**Setup:**

- I have a website which allows people to login with their facebook
  account. (I obviously created a FB app which allows them to do so)

  On that site a logged in user is (successfully) able to send private messages to other users of the app through the "send" method of FB.ui based on their userid

**Additional info:**

As you may know, a Facebook inbox consist of "2 inboxes", you have your "primary inbox" and an "other" inbox where all the messages usually go of people you are no friends with (or not related to). 
If you click "edit preferences" on the inbox you get these options:
1) Basic Filtering (Recommended)
Mostly see messages from friends or people you may know.

2) Strict Filtering
Mostly see messages from friends. Messages from people you want to hear from may go to your Other folder.


Now, I have been able to test the 'send' method successfully by defriending my girlfriend and then sending her a message through the "method". > goes straight to her 'primary inbox' and she gets the "new message warning" in the top facebook toolbar.


**Main question/concern:**
Can I be absolutely certain that every message sent to other users of my app through my websites FB.ui "send" method get delivered into their primary inbox, without being shuvved away in the "other mailbox".
I need to be sure that people get the "new message" warning in the top bar of their Facebook.

**Extra**

Do I need to ask for a special permission to be able to do this ("this" meaning the making sure part ...)? 
I currently have : `'scope'            => 'read_stream, publish_stream, email, user_about_me', (etc...)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to guarantee your message ends up in the primary mailbox other than using the new "pay to message" feature. If a user has previously had a negative interaction with your app, your message will probably end up in the user's "other" folder.

You might be better off sending a [request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) than a message. Unless the user blocks your app, these will show in both the toolbar and the upper right=hand corner of the web app.

Comment: tnx for the swift reply. Not too concerned about the user , after having negative interaction with the app, receiving further messages in the "other" folder.
What I want to achieve is that users of my webapp/site get in contact (on facebook).
I've tried your suggestion of using request. While this works (shows up in toolbar) there first is a(n ugly) Phishing warning and then a short user entered message (good), followed by a link back to my 'canvas' : where I would need to do further handling.
Seems a bit too cumbersome for my purpose =/ I just want them to be able to exchange messages.